# How do you run non-GUI version of Inno Script Studio from bash?

Tags: inno-setup, git-bash

I have a .iss file created in Inno Script Studio.  It has a pre-compilation step which is a feature specific to Inno Script Studio.  I can run my .iss file from a Command Prompt window (which is running *cmd.exe*, right?).  The command looks like,

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Inno Script Studio\isstudio.exe" -compile myscript.iss
```

If instead, I run */c/system/windows32/cmd* from a Git bash window and then try the same command I get an error popup with 'I/O Error 6'.  Why?  Through experimentation the problem seems to be with the *myscript.iss* argument: if I leave off that argument the *isstudio* simply complains that the argument is missing.

I have tried various escaping and quoting changes to the command but nothing fixes it.  I tried running *cmd* in a fresh environment with *env -i*.  I have tried providing the full path to the file using a DOS style path with C: and backslashes.

And I tried creating a .bat file with the above command in it: same error.

Comment: Your command might have been correct. The problem is related to how the Inno Script Studio outputs to the console. I've tried to run it from the Git Bash and got the (Delphi's exception) I/O error 105 which occurs when you attempt to write to the stdout without an attached console. The Inno Script Studio is a GUI application and as such must attach to the console *manually*. And that fails for some reason in the Git Bash console. So I'm afraid you won't be able to run it without the cmd prompt. It's just a consequence of mixing GUI and console Delphi application.

Comment: But you can try to enter the cmd command prompt (`cmd /C`), execute the Inno Script Studio command and exit the cmd command prompt (but if that will help I don't know).

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I think your suggestion of 'entering the command prompt'  is exactly what I did when I ran /c/system/windows32/cmd from Git Bash (and I did use the /C option).  So that doesn't help.  I guess there must be something fundamentally different between running Command Prompt from the Start Menu and running cmd from the command line.  As you suggest, it seems that cmd  must detect the graphical environment it was run from and 'attach' to it.  Maybe you should answer the question by responding that it simply is not possible?

Comment: It's vice versa. Application attaches to console. And the Inno Script Studio tool fails to do so in that Git Bash console. I've tried to make a pure Delphi console application and there was no problem, so it must be something in that manual attaching to console of this mixed GUI and console Inno Script Studio tool. And yes, this is the ISS's bug, hence it is not possible at this time.